# Dual boot operating system selection menu with two hard disks

Tags: multi-boot

I have two hard disks: one with windows and one with linux. While booting, computer is not showing option for selecting the operating system. How can I add menu for selecting which operating system I want to boot?

Comment: This website is about programming topics.

Comment: Without knowing *which* os its showing, its hard to tell what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a boot loader, a good one is [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)

It get installed at the time you install Linux on your disk, Since you have two disks, in case you can not setup the partitions in the setup board configuration, it is possible you need to do a special configuration of the physical jumpers that are in the back of the disks.

Some references:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/10/27/dual-boot-ubuntu-11-10-windows-7-on-a-pc-with-2-hard-drives/

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/09/12/7-tips-for-dual-booting-linux-distributions-and-windows/

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=179902

Comment: You mean GRUB..